# Wordpress doesn't update changes

Tags: wordpress, caching, plugins, data-cleaning

i have couple of plugins on my wordpress and all of them are working great , nothing wrong .

until 8h ago before i went to sleep ...

everytime i make a change it doesn't show :(

i tried clearing caches on my computer and using W3-total cache to clean it up but it said there is no cache to clean it up

i used super-cache too ... said 0kb cache !!

i did tried to remove the plugins and deactivate them ... still nothing !

i even removed everything in that page ... it still show the old stuff , its driving me crazy :(

one of the plugin kinda stopped working or maybe it just doesn't update too :(

nut-job.co

help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove that all cache plugins and try it.

Answer (score 0):

And the first reply happens to be someone mentioning that you should turn your cache off, but they apparently didn't actually read your post.

Have you tried checking your htaccess file to see if it's forcing the redirect. 
Check you Settings, General Setting in the writing section to see what page you have set as your home page. 
Also, try updating the url of your site in your phpmyadmin/mysql database. 
If none of these work, then you are in the exact same boat I'm in. I have no idea unless... maybe your site was hacked and there is a cron job running.

One know issue I keep hearing about is this: 
https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/03/pseudo-darkleech-server-root-infection.html
You might have some base64 code in your : wp-includes/nav-menu.php

Check it out,